# How to set points in userpoints moduel

Tags: userpoints

I am using the [**User Points**](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module to award points to user after performing below actions :

- submit story - give 10 points
- submit design
- like design
- like story

I have created rules to grant points to user after performing above events & it is working fine.

Now I want to provide a consolidated configuration page where admin can change award point 
without touching to rules.

Using this interface admin can easily change the award points.

Like :

- submit story - give 15 points.

**Can we assign Points value by variable in rule?**

If yes, how?

One way I have tried by creating content type `userpoint` and created 4 integer field for same. Where we can store value for Point n use in particular rule ->action.

Any one has done this? Please guide me.

Comment: That module uses rules for its UI - if you want a different UI, you'll need to build one from scratch. Or at least one that leverages rules components, like Drupal Commerce does. We can't guide you through a task that large, it will require quite a bit of thought and a large amount of custom coding, I should imagine. If you have specific development questions (either now, or when you get a bit further), feel free to ask those

Comment: No workaround at all ?? anyways thanks.

Comment: I doubt there's a workaround that will magically give you a non-standard UI - would be great if there was I'm sure :)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155379/points-based-tasks-pledging-and-tracking/205552#205552), Especially the "*each goal can be configured (using the admin UI) to automatically grant an amount of user points to some user, after that user completed the goal*" part of it, which seems to match with what you're looking for.