# Points-based tasks: pledging and tracking

Tags: 7, webforms, userpoints

I am a member of a social organization and run its Drupal 7 website. We will be starting a campaign in a couple of weeks to challenge members to pledge to accomplish certain points-based tasks (not related to the website), and want to track the pledges, completions, and rolled-up sums.

1. There are roughly 100 tasks, with different point values and descriptions. Tasks are individual: more than one member can pledge to do a task.
2. A member would sign up on a per-user page to complete certain tasks. The sums of a member's pledged tasks and completed tasks should be displayed on the per-user page, and there should be a summary of all members' pledged and completed points and tasks available as well.
3. A member needs to be able to return to his/her page to update pledges and completions.

I believe I can do something for this with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), but it may be somewhat awkward. I'm not sure I can do the per-member sums and the rollups easily. [User Points](http://groups.drupal.org/user-points) might help a bit, but it's not really oriented toward this. I could write a module as well, but I'm  not sure I have time to do that. Suggestions for other modules or implementing this quickly are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing to write my own module, after discovering that [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) includes the capability to create a form based on a view. This is a feature of Views that is not that well known (at least by me). There's an excellent tutorial on how to use the feature: [Programmatically Creating Forms with Views in Drupal 7](https://www.isovera.com/blog/programmatically-creating-forms-views-drupal-7). Input fields can be added to a view using this feature, and their values are submitted with the form.

Each task described in the original question can now be a node. To do the point totals I will embed the view in a page and add some code to compute the totals. Eventually I may Ajaxify the page.

A key feature here is storing per-user data associated with a node, which is not that common. My module uses its own db table to store this. The [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module can also associate store per-user data per node, but it only stores a boolean and does not handle multi-valued Flags.

The module I'm working on is currently a sandbox project, [Task Pledge](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dhalbert/2479027).

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) together, by adding a number field with initial value 0 in your user fields. Every time user completes a task, validating a form submission, a value will be added to your field. That's the points field, which would be, in this case, unique. There is no sum in this case, but the field value will be automatically calculated by [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Number field, your points field, should be available in your display, not in your user register form, with the right permissions.

That's what I'm thinking as a solution right now, if tasks are webforms. Not sure about awards or how to keep track of each completed task.

I hope that would get you started.

Answer (score 2):

## Goals module

You may want to look at the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer) as a possible alternative. To start using it only requires typical administration tasks (configuration), though it does come with various hooks also for custom module development (if you want to).

Using the **Goals Extras** sub-module it integrates with the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module also: each goal can be configured (using the admin UI) to automatically grant an amount of user points to some user, after that user completed the goal.

Since the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module is entity based, it has out-of-the-box integrations with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), etc.

## Requirements mapping

I can think of multiple ways to implement your requirements. For the sake of simplicity, here is one that IMO is the most straight forward implementation.

> 1) There are roughly 100 tasks, with different point values and descriptions. Tasks are individual: more than one member can pledge to do a task.

Create a content type, say **Task**, and add any custom fields you may need, eg for storing your point values and descriptions. For each of your "*roughly 100 tasks*" (referred to as ***Task-I*** below), create a node of type *Task*.

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to create these (non global) flags to be used for flagging nodes of type "*Task*":

- **Pledge**: to indicate a pledge by the flagging user, related to Task-I.
- **Complete**: to indicate the completion of Task-I by the flagging user.

Make sure to authorize all relevant users to use these flags (of course). That way, "*more than one member can pledge to do a task*" (as in your question).

Use the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module to configure 1 goal (referred to as ***Goal-I*** below) related to Task-I, which consists of only completing 1 thing (= a "task" as defined within the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module): flag the Task-I node. While configuring Goal-I, also indicate how many points (using the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module) should be granted automatically by [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) after a user completes Goal-I.

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to allow  [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) to "*record the progress of the completion of the task related  to Goal-I*". To do so, create a rule like so:

- Rules Event: A node is flagged (by flag "completed")
- Rules Condition: The node's `nid` corresponds to the `nid` of Task-I
- Rules Action: Mark the completion of the task related to Goal-I

A more advance way to use (configure) goals, is that there could be multiple tasks, and/or they might have to be repeated multiple times, and/or they might have to happen within a given timeframe, and/or they may require some amount of time to expire in between any 2 similar tasks, .... However, Goal-I was configured to only consist of 1 task. So after the above Rules Action is executed, [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) will automatically mark Goal-I as completed.

To avoid you'd have to create (roughly) 100 such rules (1 for each Goal-I), you could consolidated them all in a single rule, by transforming the Rules Action to performing an equivalent Rules Component (using node's `nid` as a parameter of the Rules Component), whereas you'd move the Rules Condition to that Rules Component also. Other alternative could be to use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module

> 2) A member would sign up on a per-user page to complete certain tasks.

That's simply a standard user registration, where you want to ensure that such users have read access to all the Task-I nodes, and also that they are allowed to use both flags.

> The sums of a member's pledged tasks and completed tasks should be displayed on the per-user page,

Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to build the appropriate displays. Because of the modules mentioned above, they all integrate with Views very well (so creating such views should be straight forward).

> There should be a summary of all members' pledged and completed points and tasks available as well.

To create these summaries, use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (also), and/or have a look at the views (block) that comes with [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) (title = "Your completed goals").

> 3) A member needs to be able to return to his/her page to update pledges and completions.

That's a matter of flagging and unflagging Task-I.

## More details

For more details about the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module, refer to my answer to "[How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)".

Comment: I had similar question and this answer was perfect for me, thanks!